# Debit card without address

Tags: debit-card, online-banking, direct-debit

I am wondering if there is a way to get a bank account/debit card without an address to send it to. I am wanting to give the cards to people in need and be able to send money to the bank/card when needed. Is there an online bank that offers something like this? The plan is to buy the cards beforehand then register them as they are handed out?

Answer (score 1):

Debit card, no. Prepaid card, probably; some charities do use that approach to make monthly support payments, including to the homeless. You might want to find and talk to one of those groups to find out how they did it.